# Flutter custom chrome tabs plugin not working in release

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, webview, release

I am currently using [Flutter custom tab package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs). For loading the login web page. My code is working fine in a debug mode. But whenever i run flutter build APK command  and build the application then package is not working and URL is not launching in the the browser.

```
 await launch(
    loginUrl + "?channel_id=$chanelId",
    customTabsOption: CustomTabsOption(
      enableInstantApps: false,
      toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      enableDefaultShare: true,
      enableUrlBarHiding: false,
      showPageTitle: false,
      animation: CustomTabsSystemAnimation.slideIn(),
      extraCustomTabs: const <String>[
        'org.mozilla.firefox',
        'com.microsoft.emmx',
      ],
    ),
    safariVCOption: SafariViewControllerOption(
      preferredBarTintColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      preferredControlTintColor: Colors.white,
      barCollapsingEnabled: true,
      entersReaderIfAvailable: false,
      dismissButtonStyle: SafariViewControllerDismissButtonStyle.close,
    ),
  );
} catch (e) {
  // An exception is thrown if browser app is not installed on Android device.
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

Here is my code which is working fine in debug mode. Please give me the direction to resolve the above issue.